# Creating a special symbol to use in align environment

Tags: symbols

This is a bit of a silly question, but, is there a way of creating new symbols in LaTeX? Is it possible to make an emoji TeX-able? I want to label Burgers' equation in an align environment with a hamburger (like the burger emoji you may find on your smart phone).

Comment: you could include such a symbol as a very small graphic with `\includegraphic{...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can actually create symbols, however, you can use for example this workaround. Note that you have to download a burger icon as an image or create it e.g. via Ti*k*Z.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\burger}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{burger.png}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + y \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = d \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} & & \burger{}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

**Reuslt:**
[image]

**EDIT:**

A slightly tweaked solution using the burger as a `\tag*`. The size of the icon is lowered to 3 ex, and the icon vertically adjusted using the `\raisebox` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\burger}{\includegraphics[height=3ex]{burger.png}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + y \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = d \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} \tag*{\Big(\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\burger{}}\Big)}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You just need [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), not [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: Good point. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Consider giving back to the community through [voting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).